# Data in Gruff diagram from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, diagram, gruff

I was looking for some example how to extract data from database and use it in diagram created in Gruff, but failed. So I want to show in this diagram two things from data base:

Course.application.size - which would count all applications to this course

Student.size - which would show me how many students are in school

So, how should I put this data into following diagram?

```
g = Gruff::Pie.new

g.title = "Applications"
g.data("Applied", ???)
g.data("Students", ???)

send_data(g.to_blob, :disposition => 'inline', :type => 'image/png', :filename => "gruff.png")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the count in variable and use it as data in graph as shown below:

@course = Course.application.size

@student = Student.size

```
g = Gruff::Pie.new
g.title = "Applications"
g.data : "Applied", @course
g.data : "Students", @student
send_data(g.to_blob, :disposition => 'inline', :type => 'image/png', :filename => "gruff.png")
```